# ¿Cómo hacer un chat con WebRTC?

Tags: javascript

Intenté usar la función ServiceWorker en un script de un archivo html:

```
net=ServiceWorker('chat11.js')
```

Pero me da un error:

> "Illegal Constructor"

Entonces supuse que se usaba de otra manera, y la encontré:

```
<script>

    if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('chat11.js').then(function(reg){
        console.log('ServiceWorker launched sucesfully.',reg)
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
```

Nuevamente dio otro error:

> "DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed (see:
>   https://goo.gl/Y0ZkNV)."

Y yo leí la página, y decía que tenía que usar un dominio seguro. Me di cuenta en esta misma pregunta que los serviceSocket no trabajan como chats, entonces, intenté iniciar un WebRTC:

```
net=new RTCPeerConnection()
```

Es curioso, porque me dio un error en chrome:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined

Entonces, ¿Podrían decirme cómo configurar el dominio público para que me acepte los WebRTC en chrome y pueda usarlos tanto en Google Chrome como en Mozilla Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que has mal entendido la función de un `Service Worker` su función es similar a la de un proxy que está en el medio de las peticiones que haga el cliente (la pestaña del navegador con tu página) y el servidor donde tengas alojada la aplicación, lo que le permite al `Service Worker` interceptar las peticiones, crear una cache de las peticiones, modificar las peticiones antes de enviarlas, modificar la respuesta enviada por el servidor, funcionar sin conexión utilizando la cache.

Ya que el `Service Worker` puede leer y modificar todas las peticiones a fin de evitar ataques tipo "Man in the Middle" producto de la suplantación del script que contiene el código del `Service Worker` el contenido de tu sitio web debe ser servido usando HTTPS cuando hayas desplegado tu aplicación a producción para que el navegador te permita registrar el `Service Worker`, en caso de no usar HTTPS la página funcionará con normalidad solo la lógica del `Service Worker` no estará disponible esto no afectará el desempeño del resto de la aplicación, mientras desarrolles y depures la aplicación desde `localhost` el navegador hará una excepción a esta política de seguridad y cargará el `Service Worker` para que funcione con normalidad.

Referencias: [Service Worker API en Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), [Service Workers: an Introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers)

Comment: Creí que funcionaría como un SharedWorker, pero en lugar de comunicarse con otra ventana, se comunicaría con otros ordenadores, pero me lo detecta como "ilegal", así que no se puede hacer nada según mi alcance.

Comment: No, tampoco puedes usar un `Shared Worker` para eso, si bien tanto los `Web Worker` como los `Service Worker` proveen una manera de comunicarse a través de eventos, esto se utiliza para notificar cuando se termina un proceso y enviar la respuesta al script que creó el worker.

Comment: Si deseas crear un chat puedes utilizar `WebSocket` o `WebRTC` , también podrías utilizar http://benzap.github.io/flyer.js/

Comment: WebSocket no conecta con el servidor de hostinger, da el siguiente error:
"Firefox no puede establecer una conexión con el servidor en ws://tatopatato.esy.es/chat12.htm."

Comment: Y WebRTC da el mismo error.

Comment: Para el caso de los `WebSocket` el servidor debe soportar el protocolo, y el `WebRTC` hay que implementar la funcionalidad para que el servidor permita a los usuarios intercambiar los detalles de la conexión para que puedan comunicarse entre sí.

Comment: ¿Sabes como podría configurar ese apartado? (Si me disculpas, cambio el título de la pregunta)

Comment: Un momento, el WebRTC funciona en firefox, pero en chrome no me lo detecta como una función. ¿Qué hago para solucionarlo?

Comment: @TatoBroh Si esta respuesta había servido para solucionar lo que estabas preguntando (incluso si sirvió para entender que no deberías usar esto), se recomienda aceptar esta respuesta, y realizar una nueva pregunta con el nuevo tema.

Comment: Está complicado, ya que si hago una nueva pregunta con los WebRTC lo más posible es que la borren.

Comment: @TatoBroh disculpa pero la finalidad de stackoverflow es responder a preguntas especificas no explicar paso a paso como realizar a cabo una implementación, ya que sería muy largo de explicar cómo realizar un chat (en tu caso) ya que involucra distintas tecnologias

Comment: A huevo, entonces dime por qué fallan los WebSocket, respóndeme esa pregunta específica.

Comment: Que tienes que irte a otra pregunta mía, claro...